# Поиск ближайшего семейства шрифтов

Tags: шрифты, ttf

У меня есть `ttf` файл с описанием шрифта и множество используемых символов.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно найти несколько ближайших шрифтов (названий шрифтов) к шрифту, задаваемому моим `ttf` файлом (ближайшесть определяется по множеству используемых символов)?